# Powershell Script is throws Casting Error in Windows 7 and NOT Windows 10

Tags: .net, powershell, casting, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

First, I'm going to assume that the issue that I'm facing is a .Net issue because I can run the script successfully in Windows 10 but not on Windows 7.

Below is the error that I am getting. So, I attempted to fix the issue by placing "" (double quotes) around the $CharNum variable to correct the issue. However, it does not work.

So, if anyone can shed some light into this issue and help me understand why this script works in Windows 10 and NOT Windows 7 I'd greatly appreciate it. Also, if you can help me correct the code so it's compatible in both version of Windows it would be very much appreciated.

Again, I'll assume .Net is the culprit.

[image: Casting Error]

```
function GetRandomPassword ([char] $length=10, $count=1) {

if ($length -lt 4) {return $null}

# Define list of numbers, this will be CharType 1
$numbers=$null
For ($a=48;$a –le 57;$a++) {$numbers+=,[char][byte]$a }

# Define list of uppercase letters, this will be CharType 2
$uppercase=$null
For ($a=65;$a –le 90;$a++) {$uppercase+=,[char][byte]$a }

# Define list of lowercase letters, this will be CharType 3
$lowercase=$null
For ($a=97;$a –le 122;$a++) {$lowercase+=,[char][byte]$a }

# Define list of special characters, this will be CharType 4
$specialchars=$null
For ($a=33;$a –le 33;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }
For ($a=63;$a –le 64;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }
For ($a=61;$a –le 61;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }
For ($a=45;$a –le 46;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }
For ($a=35;$a –le 38;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }
For ($a=42;$a –le 43;$a++) {$specialchars+=,[char][byte]$a }



# Need to ensure that result contains at least one of each CharType
# Initialize buffer for each character in the password
$Buffer = @()
For ($a=1;$a –le $length;$a++) {$Buffer+=0 }

# Randomly chose one character to be number
while ($true) {
$CharNum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)
if ($Buffer["$CharNum"] -eq 0) {$Buffer["$CharNum"] = 1; break}
}

# Randomly chose one character to be uppercase
while ($true) {
    $CharNum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)
    if ($Buffer["$CharNum"] -eq 0) {$Buffer["$CharNum"] = 2; break}
}

# Randomly chose one character to be lowercase
while ($true) {
    $CharNum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)
    if ($Buffer["$CharNum"] -eq 0) {$Buffer["$CharNum"] = 3; break}
}

# Randomly chose one character to be special
while ($true) {
    $CharNum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)
    if ($Buffer["$CharNum"] -eq 0) {$Buffer["$CharNum"] = 4; break}
}

# Cycle through buffer to get a random character from the available types
# if the buffer already contains the CharType then use that type
$Password = ""
foreach ($CharType in $Buffer) {
    if ($CharType -eq 0) {$CharType = ((1,2,3,4)|Get-Random)}
    switch ($CharType) {
        1 {$Password+=($numbers | GET-RANDOM)}
        2 {$Password+=($uppercase | GET-RANDOM)}
        3 {$Password+=($lowercase | GET-RANDOM)}
        4 {$Password+=($specialchars | GET-RANDOM)}
    }
}
return $Password
```

}

## Change the path to the correct destination

$PW = GetRandomPassword -length 25 -count 300 >> C:\ctdInstall\PW.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure they run the same powershell version? Win10 has PS 5.0 built-in while Win7 has PS2.0. Newer powershell versions might have some extra safeguards that fixes the casting error.

More importantly: why are you using char? :S

Change it to `[int]$length = 10` and all your problems will disappear.

```
Function GetRandomPassword ([int] $length=10, $count=1) {
```

Comment: Interesting. So it really comes down to the version of Powershell and not the .Net version. Let me implement this change and test it out.

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Powershell has lots of features to make it easier to use .NET functions since its a scripting language. Also, 25 is two chars and was truncated to 2 as you could see in the error.

Comment: Frode,

Actually, by changing $length from char to int will not work would it? The reason why char is being used is because I am selecting the length of the password, which includes special case, upper case, lower case, and numbers.

Right, I see that it was truncated, but throws me off as to why it won't output the random password. It's still a char, correct?

Comment: The reason 2 doesn't work is probably because of the different powershell versions (and it's casting magic). 2 is an int. 2.0 would be a double. You only use length for max (numerical) value for get-random => it will always be a number => it's an int, not a char.

Comment: So after changing char to int I get new error: 

"Missing statement in body in while loop" 

<<<<< $Charnum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)

:ParseError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
: MissingLoopStatement

Comment: It should work. :-/ what's the length value still 25? I don't have a computer available to test so if you still haven't solved it tomorrow I could take a look at it :-)

Comment: Sure. So the value is still set to 25 but here is the error:

PS > 
Missing statement body in while loop.
At  char:9
+<<<< $CharNum = (Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum $length)
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingLoopStatement

Comment: Missing statement has nothing todo with length object-type. You have probably mixed up some curly braces in one of the while($true)-loops (which are horrible design btw. You should always avoid while($true)-loops, even with breaks.)

Comment: Thanks, I need to look to see why this loop error is being thrown. I would like to sharpen my skills on Powershell and still learning better techniques.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer. I converted char to int and NO issues. I had erased a bracket somewhere, but found that quick. But you definitely helped me resolve this! Thanks man!

Comment: If this solved your problem, remember to mark it as the answer. :-). If you want to test you could upgrade the win7 machine to WMF 3.0, 4.0 and 5.0 to see when powershell fixed the conversion problem from char 2 to 2.0 double.

Comment: Definitely marked it as answer. How can I request you as a friend? You seem very knowledgeable and I can learn quite a bit from you.

Comment: Hehe, thanks. Unfortunately I don't think that is possible. I'm not as active as I used to be here, but submit your questions and we might talk again. If not then one of the other experienced regulars here will help you. :-)

Comment: Thanks buddy. You're help was greatly appreciated. It will take me time to become an experienced programmer/scripter, but I'm hoping I can learn a lot from this community. It's people like you that I am grateful for.... always willing to help and allow others to learn and grow. :-)